# There is conflict bootstrap.css with jquery.js (ajax). What can I do?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to use bootstrap & jquery(ajax) in my code. But .activeEv doesn't work. If I connect bootstrap.css than the code (ajax) is unexpected. But, if I disconnect bootstrap.css, than .activeEv is expected. What can I do in this siyuation?
P.S.: sorry for my englash.
header_style.css:

```
.activeEv{
color: red !important; 
}
```

welcome.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="bootstrap-3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  <!-- If I delete this string, than ".activeEv" operates as expected -->
<!--
<link href="../../public/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    <!-- If I use this string than ".activeEv" operate as expected, but bootstrap will be unexpected-->
-->
<link href="bootstrap-3/css/header_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
@include('header')

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container ">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav centermenu">
                        <li  class="loadBtn"><a name="top"> languages </a></li>
                        <li  class="loadBtn"><a> targets      </a></li>
                        <li  class="loadBtn"><a> bd           </a></li>
                        <li  class="loadBtn"><a> instruction  </a></li>
                        <li  class="loadBtn"><a> cooperation  </a></li>
                    </ul>
</div></div></div></div></div>

<div class="container">
    <div id="content"><a></a> </div>
</div>
```

Browser console:

```
An error occurred while parsing the value of "background-color".    bootstrap.css:6408:25
```

Comment: Are you testing in mozilla firefox?

Comment: Yes, Mozila & Chrome

Comment: Are you experiencing the issue in both the browser or only in mozilla?

Comment: I am experiencing the issue in the both browsers (mozila, chrome)